# Coldfusion builder & cfclient building

Tags: cordova, coldfusion, builder

When using the new cfclient tag in coldfusion 11 I believe that coldfusion builder 3 will build this and convert the code to JavaScript and adapt as necessary to produce a phonegap build.
I wonder if it is coldfusion builder that does the cfclient conversion or is it actually the phonegap build itself that recognises the cfclient tags?

So if I used a text editor with cfclient etc and built this with phonegap directly then would these tags be converted?

I'm just curious so that we will know if coldfusion builder product itself is really needed for this.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The CFML compilation is done by the CF Server, not ColdFusion Builder (although CFB ships with CF built-in, these days). That said, it's all rolled up in the packaging process that CFB runs through, so I imagine you *do* need CFB, yes.

Comment: You need to have CFBuilder to build it correctly. It's a requirement.

Comment: Thanks Adam & Matt. that's answers my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adam correctly explains

The CFML compilation is done by the CF Server, not ColdFusion Builder (although CFB ships with CF built-in, these days). That said, it's all rolled up in the packaging process that CFB runs through, so I imagine you do need CFB, yes. –